# Get a letter index inside a text node?

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri

```
<span class="word">fab
  <span class="green">u</span>lous
</span>
```

The piece of HTML is just a word "fabulous" with a green letter "u". I need to find out the index of the green letter in this word.

The CSS `.word` selects the whole word, and `.green` can tell the letter 'u' is green. But I can't know actually which 'u' is green.

How can I get the green letter position?

Comment: what exactly you want ?

Comment: Use `css('.word').children` then go through all of children and look up for `green` span...

Comment: I am not aware of the usage of the children method. It just does the job here. Thanks a lot for your great answer! It's just what I need for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you would like to find the position of the green letter in a word, so I could do this as:

```
require 'nokogiri'

str1 = '<span class="word">fab<span class="green">u</span>lous</span>'
str2 = '<span class="word">fabulo<span class="green">u</span>s</span>'

def get_green str
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
  sh = 0
  doc.css('.word').children.each do |c|
    sh += c.text.length
    if c['class'] == 'green'
      break
    end
  end
  sh - 1
end

p get_green(str1)
p get_green(str2)
```

The output is:

```
# => 3
# => 6
```

---

The occurrence and position of a green letter (if any):

```
require 'nokogiri'

str1 = '<span class="word">fab<span class="green">u</span>lous</span>'
str2 = '<span class="word">fabulo<span class="green">u</span>s</span>'
str3 = '<span class="word">fabulo<span class="red">u</span>s</span>'

def get_green str
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(str)
  char = doc.css('.word .green').text
  return [-1, -1] if char == ""
  occurance = 0
  position = 0
  doc.css('.word').children.each do |el|
    break if el['class'] == 'green'
    position += el.text.length
    occurance += el.text.chars.select{|ch| ch == char}.length
  end
  [occurance + 1, position]
end

p get_green(str1)
p get_green(str2)
p get_green(str3)
```

Output:

```
# => [1, 3]
# => [2, 6]
# => [-1, -1]
```

Comment: why 3, I think it should be like 1 ? *1* means first `u`. Not *6*..it is like *2nd*, `u`.

Comment: @ArupRakshit , just thought it should return `position` of green letter... In my opinion `index == position` ;)

Comment: +1.... anyway.. Good approach.What I am thinking in my case, I couldn't code it. :(

Comment: @ArupRakshit , updated with your case.